# Dynamic Modal with Form - Undefiend Post Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on a user edit modal, the modal display's perfectly fine however the form submission is not working properly. I've looked at console output and I can't spot where my logic is failing me. I know I have to create the modal, fill the content, display the modal and then submit the form.

Thanks for the help!

Here is the code:

```
var update_user_display = function() {
    $("body").on('click', '.update_user_display', function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      var user_id = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'));
      var user_login = $(this).attr('data-user');
      var user_password = $(this).attr('data-password');
      var user_email = $(this).attr('data-email');
      var user_role = $(this).attr('data-role');

      var output = '';
      output += '<table class="user_data table table-striped table-condensed" id="clients">';
      output += '<thead>';
      output += '<tr>';
      output += '<th>Employee Name</th>';
      output += '<th>Password</th>';
      output += '<th>Email Address</th>';
      output += '<th>Role</th>';
      output += '</tr>';
      output += '</thead>';
      output += '<tbody>';
      output += '<form method="post" class="user_edit_form form-horizontal" action="..api/admin/edit_user">';
      output += '<input class="user_id" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="' + user_id + '" />';
      output += '<td><input type="text" id="login" name="login" value="' + user_login + '" /></td>';
      output += '<td><input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="' + user_password + '" /></td>';
      output += '<td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="' + user_email + '" /></td>';
      output += '<td><input type="text" id="role" name="role" value="' + user_role + '" /></td>';
      output += '<td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></td>';
      output += '</form>';
      output += '</tbody>';
      output += '</table>';

      // The BS3 Modal
      var user_modal = $("#modal-user");
      // Populate the Data
      user_modal.find('.modal-title').html('User Editor');
      user_modal.find('.modal-body').html(output);
      // Show the Modal
      user_modal.modal('show');

      // Proccess Data Changes
      $("#submit").on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

       var form = $(this);
       var url = $(this).attr('action');

       console.log(url);

       var postData = {
           user_id: parseInt($(this).attr('user_id')),
           login: $(this).find('.login').val(),
           password: $(this).find('password').val(),
           email: $(this).find('email').val(),
           role: $(this).find('role').val()
       };

       console.log(postData);

       $.post(url, postData, function(o) {
           if(o.result == 1) {

               Result.success("Successfuly Updated User.");
               // Hide the Modal
              default_modal.modal('hide');
           } else {
               Result.error("No Changes Made.");
          }
       }, 'json');
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in the form submit event handler:

- every time you click to edit a user, you rebind the handler of the submit element(`$('#submit').on('click', function(evt) {   });`), ending up with multiple handlers bound that element. Instead, you should use event delegation, which is only executed once, on DOM ready:
      `$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(){   })`
- the `$(this)` object is the element being clicked (`<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />`), and not the form element.
- give each form input appropiate ids.
- `postData.user_id` should get its value from an input, not from `user_id` attribute, which is not present anywhere in form.

So the correct code should be:

```
  // Proccess Data Changes
  $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    var $form = $('form.user_edit_form');
    var url = $form.attr('action');

    console.log(url);

    var postData = {
       user_id: parseInt($('#user_id').val()),
       login: $('#login').val(),
       password: $('#password').val(),
       email: $('#email').val(),
       role: $('#role').val()
    };

    console.log(postData);

    $.post(url, postData, function(o) {
       if(o.result == 1) {

           Result.success("Successfuly Updated User.");
           // Hide the Modal
          default_modal.modal('hide');
       } else {
           Result.error("No Changes Made.");
      }
    }, 'json');
  });
```

Also jQuery DOM tree traversal functions will not work properly for a `<form>` element wrapped in a `<table>`:

```
 <table>
    <form>
       ...
    </form>
 </table>
```

Instead you should use:

```
<form>
     <table>
       ...
     </table>
</form>
```